# How can I check a value is in a range in IList

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, list, linq

I have the following code which returns `IList<>`

```
var productCodes = await ProductsService.GetAllProductsAsync();
```

My Model:

```
public int ProductStartCode { get; set; }
public int ProducEndCode { get; set; }
```

When create a new product code range, I would like to check the new code doesn't overlap with the existing Product codes

My Product code looks like as follows:

```
 ProductStartCode  ProductEndCode 
   100001            100003
   100004            100008
   100009            100011
```

What I am trying to accomplish I need to check,

```
For example if I enter: 100001, 100002, 100003 are overlapping since they in between 100001 & 100002 range, 
             100004, 100005, 100006, 100007,100008 are also overlapping since they in between 100004 & 100008 range,
```

Comment: So are you trying to say `productCodes` is an `IList<Model>` where your `Model` has properties `ProductStartCode` and `ProductEndCode`?

Comment: When you say "if I enter" do you mean if you provide a start code and end code, or a list of possible codes, or...???

Comment: @NetMage Yes, that's what I am trying to say `productCodes`  return is an `IList<Model>` and  When I enter the `ProductStartCode` and `ProductEndCode`

Comment: What is `100001,100002,100003` then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a list of ranges, and a possible range to check for overlap, see if the start or end of the possible range is between any of the ranges in the list:

```
var isOverlapping = productCodes.Any(p => p.ProductStartCode <= possibleStartCode && possibleStartCode <= p.ProductEndCode) ||
                    productCodes.Any(p => p.ProductStartCode <= possibleEndCode && possibleEndCode <= p.ProductEndCode);
```

Comment: Thanks NetMage, I am trying it.